# Set Escape in a View

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I currently am attempting to run a script which contains a case statement where I need to match on the string 'Prod. & Mat.'

When running the script in a worksheet, I simply precede my entire script by running, 
set escape '\'
Then I run my select statement which includes the case portion written as 'Prod. \& Mat.'

All matches up as expected. However, I need to generate this same script in a view. As you know the view begins with the header...

Create or replace force view "database.table" as .....

My problem, I cannot figure out how/get the view to run and acknowledge the set escape '\' piece, so my results do not match to my 'Prod. & Mat.' portion.

How or where do I insert my set escape clause, or is there another way to avoid the & problem within a view?

Comment: If you're including the fixed value when you create the view then the escape value in the session will apply for the create statement (but `set define off` might be better anyway) and it doesn't matter afterwards. If not and you're asking about querying the view with that value then the session settings apply. The ampersand being interpreted as a substitution variable is a client thing, it doesn't apply within the DB, e.g. in the stored view definition.

Comment: Thank you for the input, set define off worked perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `set define off`before running your create view script, and then `set define on` afterwards, if you want ampersands to represent parameters again.

That way, & is treated as just another character - there will be no need to escape it.